# Method execution time difference in same flow using Micrometer @Timed annotation

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-cloudwatch

Hope you are doing well.

We have a requirement to get the time difference between two method execution of the same flow and send it to Amazon Cloud watch metrics. As of now, I'm able to get the method time execution for each flow. For example:

```
    @Timed("step1")
    public void step1(){
        //some logic
        step2();
        //some logic
    }

    @Timed("step2")
    public void step2(){
        // some logic
        step3();
        //some logic
    }
    @Timed("step3")
    public void step3(){
        // some logic
    }
```

So here I'm able to get the data for each method, but is there any way to get the data for method execution of step1 only i.e. (step1 = step1 - step2 - step3)?, and send it to Cloudwatch without doing manual logging?

Thanks in advance.

Regards